# Exception logging in production

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using Exceptional in order to track exceptions and errors from my Google Chrome Extension in production. The extension is currently concatenating and compressing all javascript files before release. A side effect of this release flow is that you end up with rather ambigious error messages. See example below:

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined" On line 2 of chrome-extension://[extension-id]/app.js`

Since the files consists of only two lines it's rather hard to spot column that caused the error.

Can this problem be solved using the JavaScript source map feature? Or is compressing javascripts inside a Google Chrome Extension even worth it since you will load locally anyway?

Thansk in advantage!

Comment: I never "compress" my scripts for my Chrome extension (although I have only one of them :P) Most advantages have some disadvantages

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this button in Chrome (prettify):

[image: Default]

[image: Prettified]

Modified by simply typing in the script. However, it does give me problems occassionally.. Not sure why, yet.
[image: Modified]

Comment: Thx! Wasen't aware of that feature. However the error is the majority of cases produced on other client's machine. Therefor I need to be able to reproduce the error locally on my machine. Which in some cases might not be possible since I don't have access to the user flow that caused the error.

Comment: Well you will really need a testexample where you can track where the error is thrown. You could also try to search for "target" in the code but since this might occur 1000x it wouldn't be that helpful. If you don't know the particular problem, then we can't help you, because "target is undefined" is really extremely general. "Target" is part of the event object and therefore a user event has taken place.. But that's all I can say..

Comment: Yes, agree. The error featured above is included as an example and it's not the real problem. I'm interested on the subject of the general approach to production error logging in the context of Google Chrome Extensions.

Comment: Please have another look at my post, I'm updating it.